# Select2: Incorrect option selected by default

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

The issue location regarding question: https://xtee.radr.eu

How to fix the second select box (Select Subsystem) that it wouldn't have the first option selected? Currently it will select  automatically: `xroad-center....` when opening the dropdown. It will also result that if I want to know information about the first option which is already selected `xroad-center`, I have to select some other option first and then re-select the `xroad-center`.

Additional question: How to reset the `Select subsystem` select when different environment is selected?

Full source code is available here:
https://github.com/tuudik/xroad6parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that after the first selection on the second box, the header option :

**<option selected>- Select subsystem: -</option>** disappears.

Do some test : remove it and see what happens. If it solve the problem, try may be to instead include it in your second ajax function : subsystem_select(val)

Comment: Yes! I totally missed it, poiting out this fixed both of problems:)
Here's the change I made: https://github.com/tuudik/xroad6parser/commit/a8cbe2170035aa562884a78f34ebad865d985e08